# The MongoDB process is shutting down each day. how run mongod forever in the server?

Tags: linux, mongodb, hostmonster

I am beginner in MongoDB and I have a problem with the execution of this in the server.

My project is hosted in servers of hostmonster.com but they don't give me support for MongoDB data bases, although they say that I can install it under my own responsability.

Then, I installed MongoDB 2.4.1 without problems into Linux 64, after, in the MongoDB bin folder (with: mongo, mongod, mongodump ... ) I created a folder called 'data' and 'data/db' for doing some tests.

from console, I connect to the server across the SSH protocol and I run

```
./mongod --dbpath 'data/db'
```

and it works.

But, I need that it run automatically forever.

I followed the steps of [Mongodb can't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405834/mongodb-cant-start) and run the next line:

```
./mongod --fork --dbpath 'data/db' --smallfiles --logpath 'data/mongodb.log' --logappend
```

It also worked, It started the process and I closed the console, this process continued running  and I could view my data across my domain.

The problem is that the process takes a day to close, ie, I can't see my data across domain, then, I need run mongod again. with:

```
./mongod --fork --dbpath 'data/db' --smallfiles --logpath 'data/mongodb.log' --logappend
```

I don't want do it everyday, my question is:

What may be the problem?, why the mongod process dies each day?

how can I run the process forever?

Sorry for my English.

Edit: Add the last error log. I don't understand it.

```
Fri Apr 12 03:19:34.577 [TTLMonitor] query local.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:141663 nreturned:0 reslen:20 141ms
Fri Apr 12 03:19:34.789 [TTLMonitor] query users.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:3 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:211595 nreturned:0 reslen:20 211ms
Fri Apr 12 03:20:57.869 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 18215ms
Fri Apr 12 03:20:57.931 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took: 8ms
Fri Apr 12 03:22:14.155 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 32ms
Fri Apr 12 03:22:14.215 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took: 14ms
Fri Apr 12 03:22:30.670 [TTLMonitor] query actarium.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:430204 nreturned:0 reslen:20 430ms
Fri Apr 12 03:23:14.825 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 7ms
Fri Apr 12 03:23:31.133 [TTLMonitor] query actarium.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:179175 nreturned:0 reslen:20 168ms
Fri Apr 12 03:25:19.201 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took: 505ms
Fri Apr 12 03:25:23.370 [TTLMonitor] query local.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:3604735 nreturned:0 reslen:20 3604ms
Fri Apr 12 03:25:25.294 [TTLMonitor] query users.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:3 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 1 locks(micros) r:3479328 nreturned:0 reslen:20 1882ms
Fri Apr 12 03:26:26.647 [TTLMonitor] query actarium.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 1 locks(micros) r:1764712 nreturned:0 reslen:20 1044ms
Fri Apr 12 04:09:27.804 [TTLMonitor] query actarium.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:200919 nreturned:0 reslen:20 200ms
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.002 got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.151 [interruptThread] now exiting
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.151 dbexit: 
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.157 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.160 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 9
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.160 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 10
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.160 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 11
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.160 [interruptThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.160 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.160 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.176 [interruptThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.176 [interruptThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.176 [interruptThread] shutdown: final commit...
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.176 [interruptThread] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.212 [interruptThread] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.220 [interruptThread] journalCleanup...
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.246 [interruptThread] removeJournalFiles
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.280 [interruptThread] error removing journal files 
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: No such file or directory: "/home2/anuncio3/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.1/bin/data/db/journal"
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.280 [interruptThread] error couldn't remove journal file during shutdown boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: No such file or directory: "/home2/anuncio3/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.1/bin/data/db/journal"
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.285 shutdown failed with exception
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.285 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: check server/mongo logs for error messages?

Comment: ready, I added the error log information.

Comment: It seems like the TTL monitor may have encountered an error

Comment: Although your second command should work, can you check once by using nohup mode ?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is here:

```
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.002 got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.151 [interruptThread] now exiting
```

Your process is receiving signal 15, which is the default kill signal. It's possible that their systems are automatically killing long-running processes or something similar. If that is indeed what's happening, then your host would have to resolve that.

Additionally, these errors:

```
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.280 [interruptThread] error removing journal files 
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: No such file or directory: "/home2/anuncio3/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.1/bin/data/db/journal"
Fri Apr 12 04:43:54.280 [interruptThread] error couldn't remove journal file during shutdown boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: No such file or directory: "/home2/anuncio3/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.1/bin/data/db/journal"
```

indicate that something is wrong with your install's data directory. The journal files either don't exist, or are going missing; if some process on the system is trying to clean things up, then it wouldn't surprise me if something is nuking your journal files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but my experience might be helpful for other reviewers. 
Based on my tests, They only let you run a program for 5 minutes (sometimes more than this) before killing it, so it’s fairly useless to install MongoDB unless you have a dedicated IP.